# question on tangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X$ be a manifold and consider its tangent bundle $T(X)$ and let $p$ be the usual map $T(X) \to X$. Then why is it locally trivial ? i.e why for all $x\in X$ exist open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $p^{-1}(U) =U \times T_x(X)$ ?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a vector bundle?

Comment: Nope.. I just started reading today

Comment: In a local coordinate neighborhood $(U,\varphi)$, map $(x,v)\in p^{-1}(U)$ to $(x,T\varphi(v))$. Therefore $p^{-1}(U)\simeq U\times\mathbb R^n$, $n$ being the dimension of $X$. $T_x(X)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, and you are done.